# How to create a new column with the continent names of each country?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list of countries in a column and I need to get their continent in a new column.

My list has 180 different countries

***country***

Switzerland
France
Denmark
China
Argentina

and I need to get their continents like the following one

**country -continent**

Switzerland - europe

France - europe

Denmark - europe

China - asia

Argentina - america

I read something about pycountry-convert, but my apologies I couldn't find good documentation or examples.

You can see my code and the data frame [here](https://kyso.io/helenadomo/environment-health-per-country)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get your question, you first need to convert the country name to the **alpha2** format and then check for the continent. This is one approach. You need to do the following :-

- traverse through each item in your country's column and apply the following transform

> country_name_to_country_alpha2(cn_name, cn_name_format="default")

- Then you need to apply the transform on the above generated column

> country_alpha2_to_continent_code()

This is the basic idea behind doing this. If you need any more clarifications please reach out.

Comment: Thank you capt2101akash.
I converted the each country name to an alpha2 format, using the following.

`import country_converter as coco;
names = df.index.tolist();
names = ['GR' if (x == 'EL') else x for x in names];
names = ['GB' if (x == 'UK') else x for x in names];
iso3 = coco.convert(names=names, to='ISO3', not_found=None);
`

But I don't know how to do the rest, do you mind giving me an example?

Comment: You just have to use pycountry-convert package of python. In that package you have a function called `country_alpha2_to_continent_code()` you need to apply that in order to get the continent code of each country.